# Поиск корреляции между двумя изображениями

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, numpy, float

Всем хай, у меня задание: написать 2д функцию для поиска корреляции между двумя изображениями, которая на входе получит два изображения, а на выход даст изображение корреляции. Использовать надо numpy, но только basic math. Так вот, в процессе выполнения столкнулся с проблемой:***IndexError: index 5434 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5434***, я уже её гуглил, но не понимаю, что именно мне нужно изменить, прикрепляю код, надеюсь на подсказки.

```
img = PIL.Image.open("SR1.png").convert("L")
im = numpy.array(img)
img2 = PIL.Image.open("SR61.png").convert("L")
im2 = numpy.array(img2)
np.array(im,dtype=float)
np.array(im2,dtype=float)
import math
import cmath
def correlationCoefficient(X, Y, n) : 
    sum_X = 0
    sum_Y = 0
    sum_XY = 0
    squareSum_X = 0
    squareSum_Y = 0


    i = 0
    for i in range(n) : 
        sum_X = sum_X + X[i]
        sum_Y = sum_Y + Y[i] 
        sum_XY = sum_XY + X[i] * Y[i] 
        squareSum_X = squareSum_X + X[i] * X[i] 
        squareSum_Y = squareSum_Y + Y[i] * Y[i] 

        i = i + 1

    corr = (n * sum_XY - sum_X * sum_Y)/(cmath.sqrt((n * squareSum_X - sum_X * sum_X)* (n * squareSum_Y - sum_Y * sum_Y))) 
    return corr


X = im.flatten()
Y = im2.flatten()


n = len(X) 


print ('{0:.6f}'.format(correlationCoefficient(X, Y, n)))
```

Comment: Приложите код программы в виде текста.

Comment: @becouse , приложил

Comment: Какой размер ваших картинок и какие размеры массивов im и im2 вы получаете?

Comment: @passant 143x38, 124x96
массив размером 5434

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста назначение строчек np.array(im,dtype=float)
np.array(im2,dtype=float) в вашем скрипте. Подсказка  - указанные операторы НЕ меняют типы данных в ваших массивах. Удостовериться в этом можно, например, заглянув в менеджер переменных. Как были unit8, так ими-же и остались.